# Trouble running a bash script with crontab

Tags: php, linux, bash, cron

I have a bash script that checks to see if my PHP service is running, and starts it if needed.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

KP=$(pgrep -P 1 -f script.php)
if [ "X$KP" = "X" ]
    then
        /usr/bin/nohup php /var/www/test/script.php >>/var/www/test/log.txt 2>&1 &
fi
```

I then added the following entry to `crontab -e` (as my user).

```
* * * * * /var/www/test/startup >> /var/www/test/cron.log 2>&1 &
```

The cron runs, and I can see the process when looking at `htop`. However, it doesn't seem to be working or writing to the logs. It just sits there using 0% of the CPU. the `/var/www/test/` folder is owned by my and the log files have `666` permissions.

What is wrong? Or rather, what can I change to get the error logs working so I know what's wrong?

Comment: if you run the code manually from command line, it works? `        /usr/bin/nohup php /var/www/test/script.php >>/var/www/test/log.txt 2>&1 &
`

Comment: @Crazy_Bash, the output was `[1] 1858` (the pid) and the process is running. It also seems to have written to the `log.txt` file.

Comment: it most be permissions issue, try adding sudo to crontab

Comment: But if it runs as normal user from CLI, why would it need to run as root from cron?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding debugging stuff.  Some possible failures are:

Can your user actually run the `/var/www/test/startup` script?  Can your user write to `/var/www/test/cron.log`?  I suggest just have the crontab entry as so:

```
* * * * * /var/www/test/startup
```

Any output (stdin and stderr) should be emailed to your user (unless `sendmail` is broken on this machine).

Where is `pgrep`?  Is it in the path set by `PATH=...`.  Ditto `php`

What is `$KP`?  echo it to a log file that you **know** is writable:

```
touch /tmp/mylog
chmod 666 /tmp/mylog
```

then in the script:

```
echo "I'm getting pgrep from <`type -p pgrep`>" >>/tmp/mylog
echo "KP is now <$KP>" >>/tmp/mylog
```

Perhaps the `script.php` process is already running and is owned by PID 1?

Perhaps the script does not have write permission to `/var/www/test/log.txt` ?  It does not matter that `/var/www/test` is owned by you or if `/var/www/test/log.txt` is 666, if one of the parent directory is not writable or executable by you. Double-check:

```
if [ ! -w /var/www/test/log.txt ]; then echo "Cannot write to /var/www/test/log.txt"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has something to do with nohup. It only does its special things if standard input is a terminal. But I'm not sure why this would make a difference, since there's no need to detach the background process in a cron job.

But maybe this will help:

```
(/usr/bin/nohup php /var/www/test/script.php >>/var/www/test/log.txt 2>&1 &)
```